# What kind of results can return @Formula annotation? (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In every guide or example about Hibernate's `@Formula` annotation, the result is a simple object, for example, a string or computed long number. I would like to use this annotation like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_first_table")
public class MyFirstEntity {

    @Column(name = "pattern")
    private String pattern;

    @Formula(value = "select b from MySecondEntity b where b.name like pattern")
    private Set<MySecondEntity> mySecondEntities;

}
```

Is this possible? I what to avoid `@OneToMany` annotation because changes on `my_first_table` could be problematic.

Comment: don't wait.run ur program.

Answer (score 0):

A Hibernate `@Formula` cannot contain a full SQL query like this.

It contains any SQL clause which can be a single column in a query.

For example:

```
@Formula("income * tax / 100")
```